# Swift framework

Tags: swift

Buenas, hace algunos meses había empezado a aprender Swift, pero como no le entendía de donde provenían las clases NSString, NSArray, por ejemplo, dejé de aprender. En ningún lugar encontré la respuesta a mi duda, por eso es que vengo acá a preguntárselas y pedir si me explicarían lo siguiente(lo voy a comprar con Java, por que es lo que sé):

1.¿Que framework utiliza Swift?¿Cual de todos los frameworks es como Java con el Standart Edition (SE)?. En la página de apple ponen lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que entiendo los frameworks son 5... pero dentro de cada uno de ellos hay mas o que son?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra pregunta, relacionado con lo mismo, yo al usar print()...que objeto estoy usando??? El método de que instancia o objeto es?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te estás confundiendo de conceptos. Voy a intentar explicártelo de la forma más simple posible:

Para empezar, Swift **no es un framework** sino que es un lenguaje de programación, al igual que lo es Objective-C, Java o C++. Bien, teniendo claro esto, un framework no es más que una serie de métodos/funciones escritos en un lenguaje concreto para simplificar tareas, ya sea por que se repiten a menudo o porque sería complejo implementarlas.

> Un ejemplo de framework complejo es `CoreBluetooth`. Si tuvieras que
>   programar por tu cuenta cada una de las funciones que lleva el
>   framework, te volverías loco, ya que es hardware de bajo nivel y sería
>   inviable. En cambio, gracias a tener un framework, con solo escribir
>   unos pocos métodos puedes encontrar iBeacons e interactuar con ellos, por ejemplo.

Bien, lo que nos muestras en las imágenes, no son más que todos los frameworks que incorpora `iOS` para que puedas desarrollar aplicaciones para la plataforma `iOS`. Es decir, `MapKit` te permite interactuar con los mapas de Apple, `HealthKit` te permite ver los datos de salud del móvil, `UIKit` las interfaces, etc.

Sobre las clases que mencionabas, `NSString` o `NSArray` son parte del framework `Foundation` que es el framework básico que necesitarás para poder hacer operaciones básicas con strings, por ejemplo.

Y por último, porque no entiendas que es una clase, no te desanimes, sigue adelante e intenta aprender ¡que en Internet lo tienes todo!

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta!!! Antes pasaba un montón de tiempo buscando algo que me ayude a entender mejor los frameworks de swift!

Comment: ¡De nada, para eso estamos!